# Apply CKEditor Advanced Content Filter to a string

Tags: filter, ckeditor, paste, advanced-custom-fields

How can I apply CKEditor's Advanced Content Filter to a string?

I'm trying to intercept pasted content using editor.on('paste', ...), get its ACF-filtered value, and then apply my own transformations to the filtered value. After this point, it's okay if it runs through the ACF again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reported recently a ticket which I think you'll find interesting: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11621. There's a pretty high chance that this feature will be introduced in CKEditor 4.5. (**Edit**: This feature got to CKEditor in 4.5 – [`CKEDITOR.config.pasteFilter`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFilter)).

As for your question - to apply ACF to an HTML string you need to:

1. Parse it using [`CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment-static-method-fromHtml).
2. Call [`filter.applyTo`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-method-applyTo) on document fragment created in previous step. You can either use the standard [`editor.filter`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-filter) or create your own instance with different settings.
3. Serialise document fragment back to HTML string.

For example:

```
    // Create standalone filter passing 'p' and 'b' elements.
var filter = new CKEDITOR.filter( 'p b' ),
    // Parse HTML string to pseudo DOM structure.
    fragment = CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml( '<p><b>foo</b> <i>bar</i></p>' ),
    writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter();

filter.applyTo( fragment );
fragment.writeHtml( writer );
writer.getHtml(); // -> '<p><b>foo</b> bar</p>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Reinmar's answer, if you are looking to apply cerain disallowed rules & optionally react to a paste event.

```js
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
  ev.editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
    // Standalone filter based off the existing filter.
    // If the editor is removed, so it our custom filter object.
    // We don't need to pass an editor however.
    // @see https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_filter.html
    var filter = new CKEDITOR.filter(evt.editor);
    // Allow all content.
    // @see https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules.html#special-features
    // Don't set filter.allowedContent property directly, doesn't work.
    var allowed = filter.allow({
      '$1': {
          // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
          elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
          attributes: true,
          styles: true,
          classes: true
      }
    });
    if (allowed === false) {
      console.warn('An error occured setting the custom rules.');
      return;
    }
    // Now disllow color attribute & colour background-color, text-decoration styles.
    // Format "elements [attributes, attr2]{styles}(classes)"."
    // Default is '*[color]; *{color, background-color, text-decoration}'.
    filter.disallow('*[color]; *{color, background-color, text-decoration}');
    // Filter it now.
    var fragment = CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml(evt.data.dataValue);
    var writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter();
    filter.applyTo(fragment);
    fragment.writeHtml(writer);
    var processed_html = writer.getHtml();
    // Set the value of what will be pasted.
    evt.data.dataValue = processed_html;
    console.log('Content filtered.');
    // Clean up - free up memory.
    filter.destroy();
  });
});
```