# How to insert text to CKEditor without styles but preserve semantics

Tags: ckeditor, semantics, paste

Is there a way how to paste formatted text to `ckeditor` without styles and preserving semantics?

For example this is what it pastes:

```
<h1 style="font-family: sans-serif; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); line-height: 18.2000007629395px;">An h1 header</h1>

<p style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;">Paragraphs are separated by a blank line.</p>

<p style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;">2nd paragraph.&nbsp;<em>Italic</em>,&nbsp;<strong>bold</strong>, and&nbsp;<code style="white-space: pre; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">monospace</code>. Itemized lists look like:</p>

<ul style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: 18.2000007629395px;">
    <li>this one</li>
    <li>that one</li>
    <li>the other one</li>
</ul>
```

But I want to paste this:

```
<h1>An h1 header</h1>

<p>Paragraphs are separated by a blank line.</p>

<p>2nd paragraph.&nbsp;<em>Italic</em>,&nbsp;<strong>bold</strong>, and&nbsp;<code>monospace</code>. Itemized lists look like:</p>

<ul>
    <li>this one</li>
    <li>that one</li>
    <li>the other one</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) enabled (should be enabled by default), then it will filter the pasted content according to what your editor's configuration allow. Read more in the [Content Filtering](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) guide.

However, if you disabled ACF for some reasons, or you want to filter the pasted content differently, then you can create your own [`CKEDITOR.filter`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter) instance and apply it to the [pasted data](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste). Read more in [Apply CKEditor Advanced Content Filter to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238177/apply-ckeditor-advanced-content-filter-to-a-string) on how to apply the filter to HTML string.